# Как подключиться по ssh к Azure VM от имени root?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, azure

Как создать ssh ключ и с помощью него подключиться к Azure VM от имени пользователя root?

Answer (score 1):

SSH ключ вы должны были сгенерировать при создании виртуальной машины. Там в процессе есть кнопка "Download the key and create VM"

С этим ключом логиньтесь в вашего azureuser и выполните `sudo su -`. Одной командой (в предположении что вы сохранили ключ в файл `azure.pem`):

```bash
ssh azureuser@<vm-public-ip> -i azure.pem -t "sudo su -"
```

И вы залогинены в пользователя `root`

Если вам прям не можется как хочется залогиниться в рута напрямую, то нужно отредактировать файл `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. По-умолчанию в этом файле написано

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"azureuser\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142" ssh-rsa AAAA<pub-key-base-64>= generated-by-azure
```

Вам нужно удалить как минимум `command=...`, так как эта команда выполняется по умолчанию при логине, и она завершается аварийно `exit 142`, что не даёт залогиниться как рут.

После исправления этого файла вы можете залогиниться

```
ssh root@<vm-public-ip> -i azure.pem
```

## Отдельный ключ для root

Сгенерируйте ключ

```
ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/azure_root -C "Azure VM root user" -b 2048
```

Эта команда создаст приватный и публичный ключи. Публичный ключ в файле `$HOME/.ssh/azure_root.pub`

Содержимое этого файла нужно скопировать в файл `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` на вашей виртуальной машине. Тогда вы сможете логиниться как рут

```
ssh root@<vm-public-ip> -i $HOME/.ssh/azure_root
```